# Python IDLE context menu not showing Cut, Copy, Paste

Tags: python, python-idle

I've used IDLE many times before, but after installing it on a different computer, the context menu shown when right-clicking the IDLE prompt or a Python script displayed in IDLE only displays the options "Set Breakpoint" and "Clear Breakpoint." Also, the highlighted text is deselected upon right clicking.

I've checked the configuration options, but I didn't see any relevant option and I don't recall changing the default options.

The version for Python and IDLE is 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cut`, `Copy`, and `Paste` were [added to `IDLE`'s right-click](http://bugs.python.org/issue1207589) context menu in maintenance releases of Python 2.7, 3.2, and 3.3, but not Python 3.1 which was already in security-fix mode only.  You should consider upgrading to a more recent version of Python 3: 3.3.3 is current.  There have been many, many fixes and performance improvements since 3.1.1.